# Is amplify Datastore available with appsync codegen api?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync, datastore, codegen, aws-amplify-cli

I want to use amplify datastore in my project with appsync but my graphql api generated by `amplify add codegen --apiId XXX` not by `amplify add api` so when I execute `amplify codegen models` it gives me this error `No AppSync API configured. Please add an API

Comment: did you ever solve this? running into the same problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: sorry it's about 2 years ago I didn't use amplify I can't remember